# Does the following select statement exclude the mentioned CustomerIDs

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, rdl

I want to find out if my rdl report excludes the CustomerIDs "1001", "FF" and "99998002", I don't know where and how it is defined in the report builder, but I can see the source code of the .rdl file has this select statement:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures]...
}
     ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
         (
...
 ) 
         } 
         DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM 
         ( SELECT ( -{ [Customer].[CustomerID].&amp;[1001], [Customer].[CustomerID].&amp;[99998002], [Customer].[CustomerID].&amp;[FF] } 
...
```

Which I think means it is excluding the CustomerIds, but I couldn't find any description of the syntax: " SELECT ( -{" online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign is shorthand for the keyword EXCEPT.